# VSCode C++ : triggering creation of class member function definition automatically

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

Consider `Main.cpp`:

```
//Main.cpp
#include "Main.h"

int main(){
    class SIMPLE smpl;
    smpl.setval(10);
    smpl.setname();
    smpl.printname();
}
```

and `Main.h` thus:

```
//Main.h
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
class SIMPLE {
public:
    int retval() const { return val; }
    void setval(int i) { val = i; }
    void setname();
    void printname();
private:
    int val;
    std::string name;
};
```

The member functions `setname()` and `printname()` are missing definitions. VSCode Intellisense does not seem to be able to warn the user about this. See figure below which does not have any squiggles:

[image: VSCode, no squiggles/warnings]

Visual Studio IDE, on the other hand, is able to point out the missing definitions via squiggles and allows for creation of the definition in the implementation file directly from the header file. See gif image below:

[image]

Is there a way to have VSCode cpptools extension provide these features via some settings, perhaps?